# java take String to Timestamp : error of 7 seconds?

Tags: java, timestamp

i try to transform a string in a timestamp 
i do :

```
public static Timestamp transfStringToTimestamp(String dateDerniereModifDB2Param, LogWSDTO logWSDTO) throws ExceptionWS {

    Timestamp dateDerniereModifDB2 = null;      
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS");              
    if (dateDerniereModifDB2Param != null) 
    {
        try 
        {               
            System.out.println("              *********** param : " + dateDerniereModifDB2Param);

            long qu = sdf.parse(dateDerniereModifDB2Param).getTime();

            dateDerniereModifDB2 = new Timestamp(qu);

            System.out.println("            *************** renvoi : " + dateDerniereModifDB2);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ExceptionWS("ERREUR chaine Timestamp sur méthode transfStringToTimestamp() sur Web Service UtilDate",e, logWSDTO);
        }
    }   

    return dateDerniereModifDB2;
}
```

in return i have this : 
param : 2012-12-04-16.05.30.501455
renvoi : 2012-12-04 16:13:51.455

Have you got an idea ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SSS` part of the `SimpleDateFormat` is for millseconds only

Comment: yes i understand but the string i try to pass to my function is in milliseconds : "2012-12-04-16.05.30.501455"

Comment: i try this with no miliseconds it's ok !!

Answer (score 2):

```
501455 milliseconds = 501 seconds and 455 milliseconds
                    = 8 minutes, 21 seconds and 455 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with Date:

```
try{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSS");
    Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(dateDerniereModifDB2Param);
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

I hope it will help!

Comment: Why you send value 2012-12-04-16.05.30.501455 in function and from where you get it? Shouldn't be 2012-12-04 16:13:51.455 right value? In your function everything looks ok, but you must send right value as parameter!

Comment: it is the string that db2 by visual application send to me (i can't modify this) but perhaps i try to modify after the format, thanks i try !!